# How to connect SQLAlchemy to Snowflake database using OAuth2?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I need to connect to Snowflake using SQLAlchemy but the trick is, I need to authenticate using OAuth2. Snowflake documentation only describes connecting using username and password and this cannot be used in the solution I'm building. I can authenticate using Snowflake's python connector but I see no simple path how to glue it with SQLAlchemy. I'd like to know if there is a ready solution before I write a custom interface for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `snowflake.connector.connect` to create a PEP-249 Connection to the database - [see documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#connecting-with-oauth). Then use param `creator` of `create_engine` ([docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.creator)) - it takes a callable that returns PEP-249 Connection. If you use it then URL param is ignored.

Example code:

```
def get_connection():
    return snowflake.connector.connect(
        user="<username>",
        host="<hostname>",
        account="<account_identifier>",
        authenticator="oauth",
        token="<oauth_access_token>",
        warehouse="test_warehouse",
        database="test_db",
        schema="test_schema"
    )
engine = create_engine("snowflake://not@used/db", creator=get_connection)
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this working but just adding more params in the connection URL:

```py
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
import urllib.parse

connection_url = f"snowflake://{user}:@{account}/{database}/{schema}?warehouse={warehouse}&authenticator=oauth&token={urllib.parse.quote(access_token)}"
engine = create_engine(connection_url)

with engine.begin() as connection:
    print(connection.execute('select count(*) from lineitem').fetchone())
```

If you don't want to be constructing the URL on your own, you can use `snowflake.sqlalchemy.URL` like this:

```py
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
connection_url = URL(
    user=user,
    authenticator="oauth",
    token=access_token,
    host=host,
    account=account,
    warehouse=warehouse,
    database=database,
    schema=schema
)
```